# Where to find model aircraft with moving parts?

Tags: building

I came across a model F22 raptor [here](https://www.factorydirectmodels.com/custom-desktop-model/lockheed-martin-f-22a-raptor-model-airplane-with-detailed-interior/) and [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hasegawa-Scale-F-22-Raptor-Model/dp/B0038JCAKI) but I am looking for a place where I can get one with moving parts, e.g retractable landing gear, canopy and the likes with a sizable scale, maybe 1:48 or thereabouts.

I have had no such luck online, do such models exist without having to get RC models?

Comment: This is an interesting question. It is completely unexpected and has forced me to reconsider what "model airplane" means in context of SE.Drones. Bravo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any models from this site, but it appears from their product descriptions that they have what you're looking for on [themotorpool.net](https://www.themotorpool.net/Hobby-Master-1-72-Scale-Diecast-Military-Aircraft-s/1049.htm). They have a plethora of models of all nationalities, classes, and time periods.

For example, [their Bf 110E-2 model](https://www.themotorpool.net/German-Messerschmitt-Bf-110E-2-Tropical-Fighter-p/ha1815.htm) is described as having "spinning propellers"
and the "ability to display the model with landing gear in either extended or retracted mode".

[image]

From what I can tell, almost all of their models have movable parts of some sort.

Comment: A satisfying answer, my wishlist is stacking up with models to try out. They seem to have exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help, @FlashspeedIfe